# Strange behaviour when trying to release new code composer autoloader

Tags: php, caching, composer-php, autoload, opcache

When recently deploying a PHP application we've had errors such as "Call to undefined method......" when after checking on ftp that the method is clearly in the file.

The strange part about it, is that if we edit the composer autoload files: `vendor/autoload.php` and `vendor/composer/autoload_static.php` files, literally putting a space or newline somewhere in the file. Then all of a sudden the methods resolve properly.

Anyone have any idea what's going on?

Using Apache2.4 on ubuntu 16 with php-fpm to php 5.6.31.

Also if it helps, we have the same codebase on the server on 4 different vhosts.

Have tried:

Running `composer dump-autoload`

Running `composer update`

Running `opcache_reset()` from a web page

The even funnier thing is, when we remove the newlines from the two autoload files, it breaks again. It's as if the autoload files have been cached somewhere and are identified by their hash or something.

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a lot of sense: The classes are found but you get errors on the methods?

Comment: Yep - The classes are found, but the new methods are not found within the classes. Until we add a newline to the two files mentioned above, then all of a sudden everything works.

Comment: It's more likely to be a caching problem than a problem with the autoloader. If you are using something like opcache, you could try resetting it using `opcache_reset()`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that we'd done that too

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan clear:cache`? Also make sure that when a `<?php` tag opens that it `?>` closes without any spaces after etc

Comment: Not using laravel mate